# Pylint with Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, glob, pylint

I have the following directory structure in a Django project:

```
.
├── config
├── element
├── home
├── static
├── templates
├── tree
└── user
```

I'm searching for the easiest command to run pylint on all directories that are python modules.

This would be all except 'static' and 'templates'.

I tested for example:

```
pylint --load-plugins=pylint_django --ignore=static/,templates/ */
```

But the ignore switch isn't working.

The following would work of course:

```
pylint --load-plugins=pylint_django config element home tree user
```

But I want it as dynamic as possible. When i add a new django app i could forget to update the pylint statement.

---

Edit:
When i create the following .pylintrc,

```
[MASTER]
ignore=templates,static
load-plugins=pylint_django
```

and run pylint --rcfile=.pylintrc */

it gives this result:

```
************* Module static/__init__.py
static/__init__.py:1:0: F0001: No module named static/__init__.py (fatal)
************* Module templates/__init__.py
templates/__init__.py:1:0: F0001: No module named templates/__init__.py (fatal)

--------------------------------------------------------------------
Your code has been rated at 10.00/10 (previous run: 10.00/10, +0.00)
```

---

Second edit:
This behavior seems to come with the 'pylint_django' plugin.
[I opened an issue therefore.](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint-django/issues/247)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify --ignore multiple times:

```
pylint --ignore=static --ignore=templates */
```

Or you can make a .pylintrc file, that contains this:

```
[MASTER]
ignore=static,templates
```